# I have an error in react native null is not an object ''evaluating _ReanimatedModule.default.configureProps'

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I installed react native on linux machine.I want to implement createBottomTabNavigator in my practice code.I create 5 folders and index.js inside them.
navigate.js :

```
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import Profile from './common/pages/profile';
import Home from './common/pages/home';
import Search from './common/pages/search';
import Camera from './common/pages/camera';
import Notification from './common/pages/notification';

const Navigate=createBottomTabNavigator({
    Profile:{screen:Profile},
    Home:{screen:Home},
    Camera:{screen:Camera},
    Search:{screen:Search},
    Notification:{screen:Notification}
});
export default createAppContainer(Navigate);
```

and main index.js:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import Navigate from './navigate';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Navigate);
```

now when I run in genymotion i have error:

- null is not an object ''evaluating
  _ReanimatedModule.default.configureProps'

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myinstagram",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.3.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Check if you've added **new ReanimatedPackage()** in MainApplication.java under **getPackages**

and add import from: **import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage;**

Answer (score 6):

If you are using react-native 0.6, you will just need to add
`import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage;` in your MainApplication.java

However it is supposed to add this line automatically as 0.6 supports auto-linking, but for some reason it does not add this line sometimes so please make sure to check!

Just import it and everything will be working .

(Verified on React-Native 0.61.4)

If you are using less than 0.6 than go with the @Maksym Bezruchko solution

Answer (score 2):

In the android folder, `android>app>src>main>java>com>app_name>MainApplication.java` file:
Add the following import

**`import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage;`**

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using expo-dev-client, I had to rebuild my project after installing the reanimated package and configuring the babel plugin because it contains native codes.